# Javascript error "hasText(...) is not a function"

Tags: javascript

I have the following JavaScript, which seems to declare a simple, local function `hasText`, and then call that function later.

```
function hasText(addrElem) {
    if (addrElem.value === "") {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}

var addr = [
    document.getElementById('AccountRequest_AddressLine1'),
    document.getElementById('AccountRequest_City'),
    document.getElementById('AccountRequest_Country'),
    document.getElementById('AccountRequest_State'),
    document.getElementById('AccountRequest_PostCode')
];

// Add a listener to each Address item which waits for its text box to go out of focus
addr.forEach(function (addrElem) {
    addrElem.onblur = function () {
        // Check whether or not each of the Address text boxes have text in them
        if (addr.every(this.hasText(addrElem))) {
            alert("Every text box has text!");
        }
    };
});
```

However, when I go to run this code in Chrome, I get the following error:

> TypeError: hasText(...) is not a function

Can someone please explain to me why I am having issues calling `hasText` as a function, and show how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: **Unrelated:** You're using the function `every` really wrong because you have to use the elements within that array.

Comment: Look at the error carefully. `(...)` means that `hasText(addrElem)` isn’t a function, because it isn’t. You need to pass a function to `every`, like `hasText`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `this` before `hasText(addrElem)`

Also you can simplify the body of that function:

```
function hasText(addrElem) {
    return addrElem.value !== "";
}
```

Snippet without an error:

```js
function hasText(addrElem) {
    return addrElem.value !== "";
}

var addr = [
    document.getElementById('AccountRequest_AddressLine1'),
    document.getElementById('AccountRequest_City'),
    document.getElementById('AccountRequest_Country'),
    document.getElementById('AccountRequest_State'),
    document.getElementById('AccountRequest_PostCode')
];

// Add a listener to each Address item which waits for its text box to go out of focus
addr.forEach(function (addrElem) {
    addrElem.onblur = function () {
        // Check whether or not each of the Address text boxes have text in them
        if (addr.every(hasText)) {
            alert("Every text box has text!");
        }
    };
});
```

```css
div {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="AccountRequest_AddressLine1">
<input type="text" id="AccountRequest_City">
<input type="text" id="AccountRequest_Country">
<input type="text" id="AccountRequest_State">
<input type="text" id="AccountRequest_PostCode">
```

Comment: Change the elements to `input` text

Comment: The fact that this is runnable is very appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

`hasText` is a global function, you have to call it that way:

```
if (addr.every(hasText)) {
   ...
}
```

Cheers.

Comment: The argument to `every()` should be a function reference, not a call to the function.

Comment: @Barmar: You are right. I didn't pay enough attention, just noticed it was called with `this.`. I've edited the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

- The error is the usage of the context `this` which is related to the handler of the event `onblur`, so, the function is not available there.
- Pass the function as follow: `addr.every(hasText)` because it is global.

---

```
if (addr.every(hasText)) {
    alert("Every text box has text!");
}
```

Comment: That explanation is incorrect. While it’s unclear where that `this` came from in the original code snippet, the exact error message `TypeError: hasText(...) is not a function` means that `hasText(addrElem)` was tried to be called as a function, but `hasText(addrElem)` is either `true` or `false`, not a function.

Comment: @Xufox no, the OP is trying to call a function which doesn't exist.

Comment: @Xufox: It's a handler attached to the `onblur` of DOM elements, so we do know the `this`. The error message is because `this.hasText` is `undefined`, which is not a function.

Comment: That’s not what the error tells us, though. The error would be `TypeError: hasText is not a function` or `TypeError: this.hasText is not a function` otherwise.

Comment: @Xufox no, you need to get more info about it.

Comment: @Xufox: That's a good point. The `(...)` does suggest that is successfully being invoked, which doesn't make sense given the code provided.

Comment: @Ele _“More info”_? Try this in the console: `let hasText = () => {}; addEventListener("click", function(){ this.hasText(); }); addEventListener("click", function(){ [].every(hasText()); });`, click anywhere in the document. You’ll see two errors `TypeError: this.hasText is not a function` and `TypeError: hasText(...) is not a function`, both of which due to different reasons. Why don’t the code and the error appear to match in the question? That’s what I was talking about with _“While it’s unclear where that `this` came from in the original code snippet, […]”_.